# Rails Hours:Minutes Dropdowns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, calculator, helper

I'm new to Rails and I want to create a simple time calculator:
User is presented with 2 dropdown menus that capture user inputs “hour” and “minutes”, so I can get time like 7:15. Then after some math on this time the user is given several “hour:minute” time options. What is the best way to build this logic and what helper to use? Should I create models for hours and minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build up the hour and minutes drop down.

**<%= f.select :hours, '1'..'24' %>**

**<%= f.select :minutes, '01'..'59' %>**

or you can use [gem](https://github.com/tispratik/bootstrap-timepicker-rails)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [time_select](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select) to get hours and minutes from user.